# PHP How to convert fullCalendar event data to iCalendar format

Tags: php, fullcalendar, icalendar

Is it possible to convert information about events on a calendar in fullCalendar to ical or xml for use with icalendar systems such as google calendar?

Answer (score 1):

yes: the only provision you need to make is that since fullcalendar only specifies the id as optional is that if no id is supplied you need to programatically add the uid.
you will also need to create the dtstamp property.

All other properties specified by the icalendar are already present in fullcalendar, you just need to parse the fullcalendar event object and generate the ical file accordingly

Comment: Is there a plugin available that I can use to convert the event data or will I have to do it manually for each event on the calendar assuming each event already has an id?

Comment: none that I know of but if you develop it, contribute it back :)